# Symbol for insertion of a coordinate

Tags: notation

When defining maps from higher to lower dimensional spaces explicitly, say from $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, one often sees something like this:
$$(x_0,...,x_n)\mapsto(x_0,...,\hat{x}_i,...,x_n),$$
where the hat means that $x_i$ is omitted. Is there a similar notation for the opposite, i.e. insertion of an additional coordinate (like e.g. $\check{x}_i$)?

I'd be gateful for advice.

Comment: One usually chooses the added variable to be the last one i.e. write $(x_0, \ldots, x_n, x_{n+1})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've most often seen the notation

$$ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto (x_1, \ldots, x_i, y, x_{i+1},\ldots, x_n)$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^